# English translation of Vipallāsakathā

Tags: translation

I need English translation of Pali sutta [Vipallāsakathā](https://suttacentral.net/ps1.8/pli/ms).

I am mainly interested in the following part :

> Anattani  anattāti,  asubhaṃ asubhataddasuṃ;  Sammādiṭṭhisamādānā, 
>   sabbaṃ dukkhaṃ upaccagun”ti.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the same of Sutta Pitaka Vol 13 : Sutta. Aṅ. (2): catukkanipāto [vipallāsasutta](http://84000.org/tipitaka/read/v.php?B=21&A=1410&Z=1433&eng=accesstoinsight_than), except only the end paragraph which is the sutta's summary by sāriputta-mahāsāvaka :

> These four, bhikkhus, are distortions of saññā, distortions of citta,
> distortions of diṭṭhi. Which four?
>
> In what is aniccā, bhikkhus, [seeing] permanence is a distortion of
> saññā, a distortion of citta, a distortion of diṭṭhi. In what is
> dukkha, bhikkhus, [seeing] sukha is a distortion of saññā, a
> distortion of citta, a distortion of diṭṭhi. In what is anatta,
>
> bhikkhus, [seeing] atta is a distortion of saññā, a distortion of
> citta, a distortion of diṭṭhi. In what is asubha, bhikkhus, [seeing]
> beauty is a distortion of saññā, a distortion of citta, a distortion
> of diṭṭhi.
>
> These four, bhikkhus, are distortions of saññā, distortions of citta,
> distortions of diṭṭhi.
>
> Perceiving constancy in the inconstant,
> pleasure in the stressful,
> self in what's not-self,
> attractiveness in the unattractive,
> beings, destroyed by wrong-view,
> go mad, out of their minds.
> Bound to Mara's yoke,
> from the yoke they find no rest.
> Beings go on to the wandering-on,
> leading to birth & death.
> But when Awakened Ones
> arise in the world,
> bringing light to the world,
> they proclaim the Dhamma
> leading to the stilling of stress.
> When those with discernment listen,
> they regain their senses,
> seeing      the inconstant as inconstant,
> the stressful as stressful,
> what's not-self as not-self,
> the unattractive as unattractive.
> Undertaking right view,
> they transcend all stress & suffering.

For the end paragraph in Sutta Pitaka Vol 23 : Sutta. Khu. Paṭisambhidāmaggo Mahāvagge [vipallāsakathā](http://84000.org/tipitaka/pali/roman_item_s.php?book=31&item=525&items=2), which is the sutta's summary by sāriputta-mahāsāvaka:

> These 4 vipallāsa of diṭṭhisampanna-puggaka(sotāpanna) were abandoned(by sotāpattimagga) to arise or not? Some vipallāsa were, but some not. Saññāvipallāsa, cittavipallāsa, and diṭṭhivipallāsa which taking (this object:) "impermanent (khandha) as permanent (khandha)"  were abandoned to arise. Saññāvipallāsa, cittavipallāsa which taking (this object:) "suffering (khandha) as pleasant (khandha)" still arise, but diṭṭhivipallāsa  were abandoned to arise. Saññāvipallāsa, cittavipallāsa which taking (this object:)  "foul (khandha) as beautiful (khandha)" still arise, but diṭṭhivipallāsa  were abandoned to arise. Saññāvipallāsa, cittavipallāsa, and diṭṭhivipallāsa which taking (this object:) "anattā (khandha) as attā (khandha)"  were abandoned to arise.
>
> 6 vipallāsa (3 permanent vipallāsa, 3 attā vipallāsa) were abandoned to arise and to take 2 objects (permanent object, attā object). 2 vipallāsa (1  beautiful vipallāsa, 1 pleasant vipallāsa) were abandoned to arise and to take 2 objects (beautiful object, pleasant object), but 4 vipallāsa (2  beautiful vipallāsa, 2 pleasant vipallāsa) were not abandoned to arise. (The conclusion:) 8 vipallāsa (3 permanent vipallāsa, 3 attā vipallāsa, 1  beautiful vipallāsa, and 1 pleasant vipallāsa) were abandoned to arise and to take 4 objects (permanent object, beautiful object, pleasant object, and attā object), but 4 vipallāsa (2  beautiful vipallāsa, 2 pleasant vipallāsa) were not abandoned to arise.

Answer (score 2):

Anattani anattāti (Seeing) non-self as non-self

asubhaṃ asubhataddasuṃ; Unattractiveness as unattractiveness

Sammādiṭṭhisamādānā, (he is) holding on to right view.

dukkhaṃ upaccagun”ti. (He is) above sufferings

Comment: I marked this answer down because it included "self/Atman" within brackets. When the realisation of not-self occurs, it is the mind that is above suffering and the mind the holds onto right view (rather than a "self" or "he"). The Pali suttas teach about citta vimmutti (liberation of mind) rather than atta vimmuti (liberation of self). It is proper to not study Buddhism for the purpose of building egoism. In MN 22, the Buddha called studying dhamma to build egoism as grasping a poison snake. With metta